# Finding equivalent capacitance between P and Q

Tags: capacitor

Figure below is the schematic diagram ,there  we need to find the equivalent capacitance

[image]

I know that this is a straight-forward question for most of them, because many of you are expert in the field,

Now lemme give you the things that I have tried

---

I reduce those capacitors step by step, you can clearly see what I have done by following  the images appeared in below,

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Finally it is reduced to one in the below.

[image]

So finally the answer is $$(5/8)c$$

**Now what I want to know is , does my method and the answer correct**

Comment: The 2nd step seems problematic. You can use delta-wye transform as detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).

Comment: Actually, the third step is even more problematic. You have a wire going into the middle of a capacitor. How's that supposed to work? (Hint: It doesn't.) Anyway, there's a trick to solving this type of problem: Because of the symmetry, you can show that there's never any voltage across the middle capacitor, so you can simply pretend that it isn't there -- treat it either as a short or an open circuit, it doesn't matter.

Comment: How can you treat it like that way. I mean there should be a solid argument for that @ Dave Tweed♦

Comment: Like I said, it's due to the circuit's symmetry. No matter what you do to P and Q, the voltage at both ends of that middle capacitor will be the same. No current will ever flow through it.

Comment: It didn't get it. Why the  symmetry can do a such a thing?

Comment: the symmetry implies that the same voltage will exists on both side of capacitors. so, there's no current.